# cryptocode sign doesn't work

Tags: cryptocode

For some reason /sign does not work for me, while other cryptocode operators work without problem.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[primitives]{cryptocode} % crypto diagrams
\begin{document}
$\sign$\\
$\verify$

\end{document}
```

The above code block will only produce Vfy and the logs give this error message:

```
Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \sign
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of the `cryptocode` package did you use? With version 0.40, the code compiles without error messages.

Comment: thanks, I was using 0.30. Any ideas how I can upgrade using apt?

Comment: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/134144) contains instructions on how to update different tex distributions on various operating systems. Maybe this is helpful for you.